# About Change a string list to Map List of each element and others

Tags: java-8

There is a list: ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]

I want to transform it to below structure

```
[{
    main = aaa,
    others = [bbb, ccc]
}, {
    main = bbb,
    others = [aaa, ccc]
}, {
    main = ccc,
    others = [aaa, bbb]
}]
```

Now my way is

```
List<String> list = newArrayList("aaa", "bbb", "ccc");
List<ImmutableMap<String, Object>> mainAndOthersList = list.stream().map(s -> ImmutableMap.of("main", s, "others", list.stream().filter(s2 -> !s2.equals(s)).collect(toList()))).collect(toList());
System.out.println(mainAndOthersList);
```

Are there some other manner to implement it?

Comment: There are lots of ways. Your way seems a good choice.

Comment: @Eugene Sorry your way not give much inspiration

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative without streams, that is subjectively easier or harder to read.

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("aaa", "bbb", "ccc");
List<Map<String,Object>> result = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    List<Object> innerList = new ArrayList<>(list);
    map.put((String)innerList.remove(i), innerList);
    result.add(map);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your elements inside the `List` would not be String(s) and you could use `java-9`, you can basically do the same thing streaming on indexes:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> result = IntStream.range(0, list.size())
            .mapToObj(x -> Map.of(
                    "main",
                    list.get(x),
                    "others",
                    IntStream.range(0, list.size()).filter(y -> y != x).mapToObj(list::get).collect(Collectors.toList())))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But notice, this is close to the same thing you are already doing.